# Trouble installing Grive tools on Loki

Tags: applications, release-loki, apt

When using `sudo apt-get update` in order to install grive-tools to elementary, I get this:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Am I being stupid? I got it to work perfectly with Freya.

Answer (score 1):

Freya is based on Ubuntu **14.04** and loki on **16.04**.

It looks like there is [no version of Grive-Tools for 16.04](https://launchpad.net/~thefanclub/+archive/ubuntu/grive-tools) based distributions.

Maybe you can take a look at [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) or [overgrive](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu) instead.